# Remove function in CQRS Readmodel interface?

Tags: php, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm currently working on a project that was built using Broadway (https://github.com/qandidate-labs/broadway) as a CQRS / Event Sourcing solution.

What puzzles me is to find a 'remove' and 'save' in one of the interfaces, specifically: https://github.com/qandidate-labs/broadway/blob/master/src/Broadway/ReadModel/RepositoryInterface.php

Isn't the ReadModel supposed to just read? Or am I misunderstanding what the Repository is supposed to do in CQRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think I already figured it out..The Repository in the ReadModel is used to update the readmodel to reflect the latest state of the write model.

The Projector is supposed to give a 'readonly' view on the ReadModel.

Comment: hey Oli, if it helps I wrote a high level overview of a CQRS architecture. It may help put some of the elements into place for you: [CQRS + Event Sourcing – A Step by Step Overview](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/02/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check it out!